# nodejs with tar-fs : Missing files in tar file

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with tar-fs. When I try to tar a folder with multiple directories and files up to a total of 37GB it completes without errors, But when I try to extract the files I only get files back up to approximately 8GB. I'missing files in the resulting tar file.
I have now replaced tar-fs with tar (node-tar) and this has solved this problem. This indicates that tar-fs is not working properly.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const tar = require('tar-fs');
const { pipeline, Transform } = require('stream');

exports.compress = function (opts, callback) {
        // utility
        var error = function (error) {
            callback(error);
        };
        
        // ensure callback
        callback = callback || function () {};

        // ensure opts
        opts = opts || {};

        // ensure src and dest
        if(!opts.src) return error("No source for compress!");
        if(!opts.dest) return error("No destination for compress!");

        const tarstrm = tar.pack(opts.src, {});
        const deststrm = fs.createWriteStream(opts.dest);       

        pipeline(tarstrm, deststrm, (err) => { 
            if (err) {
              console.error('An error occurred:', err);
              error(err);
              // process.exitCode = 1;
            } else {
              //console.log(hash.copy().digest('hex'));
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: If your are not on Windows, do a `tree` on src and decompress result folder and see whats missing/wrong. Combine the commands with `diff`

Comment: Not sure I understand this suggestion. I know what files are missing in the tar file, although the tar file has the expected size. Some how the headers are wrong. I get these errors when I try to extract the files: 
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors. 

On windows i get the following: 
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...

Comment: After replacing tar-fs with node-tar, I obtain a complete tar file that does not give errors with tar -tvf, however I now get some strange output:   ** tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink' **            Could this be related to the fact that I am copying data from a netapp filesystem over a cifs mount.